# Calcula moda con calificaciones ingresadas -java-

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de obtener la moda de las calificaciones que se ingresaron al inicio del programa. Para esto el programa te pregunta cuantas calificaciones se ingresan, ingresas los valores uno por uno.

Al final te imprime porcentaje de aprobados, reprobados, etc.

El ultimo paso es imprimir la moda de todas las calificaciones. Y he investigado algunos metodos, pero para esto tiene que ir definidos en un array dentro del codigo indicando cada elemento y su posicion, lo cual no es funcional para este ejemplo.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
package aprobadosreprobados;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aprobadosreprobados {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

             Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in); //creacion de objeto scanner para capturar informacion

  //designamos variables a inicializar en 0
        int muybien=0, reprobados=0, aprobados=0, bien=0, regular=0, mejorar=0, insuficiente=0, nopresento=0,calif=0, i=0, n;
        float procenteaprobados, porcentajereprobados;
        System.out.print("Ingrese el numero de alumnos: ");
        n =sc.nextInt();
        while (i<=n) //variable while con condicion de cantidad de alumnos a capturar
        {
            System.out.println("Ingresa la calificación para los alumnos de la materia de Programación orientada a objetos en una escala de 0 a 100: ");
            calif=sc.nextInt();//guarda calificacion
            if (calif>=60) {
                aprobados++;
            }else
                reprobados++;

                if (calif >= 81 && calif <= 100)
                    {
                        muybien++;
                    }
                if (calif >= 61 && calif <= 80)
                    {
                       bien ++;
                    }
                if (calif >= 41 && calif <= 60)
                    {
                       regular++;
                    }
                if (calif >= 21 && calif <= 40)
                    {
                       mejorar++;
                    }
                if (calif >= 1 && calif <= 20)
                    {
                        insuficiente++;
                    }
                if (calif == 0)
                    {
                        nopresento++;
                    }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos con calificación Muy bien: "+muybien);
        System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos con calificación Muy bien: "+bien);
        System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Muy bien: "+regular);
        System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Muy bien: "+mejorar);
        System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Muy bien: "+insuficiente);

        porcentajereprobados=100*aprobados/n;
        System.out.println("\nPorcentaje aprobados"+aprobados);

    {
    //el array para la moda iria aqui
```

}

Comment: Lo que leiste es correcto.. tenes que guardar las notas en algun lado, no solo calcular lo que necesitas a medida que lo necesitas.

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta. Más info en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tenías algunos errores en el código, por ejemplo en los `if`, ya que desde el punto de vista de las buenas prácticas de programación no es eficiente, para el caso de tu ejercicio, usar `if` **simples**, por el hecho que tiene que comprobar uno por uno, en cambio fijate que al usar**if con else if** solo entra en el que cumple la condición y termina, no sigue comprobando los `if` restantes. También fijate como están **anidados** (uno dentro de otro). Investiga un poco sobre este tema (estructuras de control). Acá va el código:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
int muybien=0, reprobados=0, aprobados=0, bien=0, regular=0, mejorar=0, insuficiente=0, nopresento=0,calif=0, i=0, n;
float porcentajereprobados=0,promMuyBien=0,promBien=0,promRegular=0,promMejorar=0,promInsuficiente=0;
System.out.print("Ingrese el numero de alumnos: ");
n =sc.nextInt();
int M[];//declaramos arreglo donde se guardarán las notas para luego calcular la moda
M =new int[n];//lo inicializamos con longitud igual a cantidad de notas, o sea n
while (i < n) //variable while con condicion de cantidad de alumnos a capturar
{
    System.out.println("Ingresa la calificación para los alumnos de la materia de Programación orientada a objetos en una escala de 0 a 100: ");
    calif=sc.nextInt();//guarda calificacion
    if (calif >=0 && calif <=100){
        if (calif>=60) {
            if (calif >= 81 && calif <= 100) muybien++;
            else if (calif >= 61 && calif <= 80) bien ++;
            aprobados++;
        }
        else {
            if (calif >= 41 && calif <= 60) regular++;
            else if (calif >= 21 && calif <= 40) mejorar++;
            else if (calif >= 1 && calif <= 20) insuficiente++;
            else nopresento++;
            reprobados++;
        }
    }
    else System.out.println("La nota ingresada es inválida");
    M[i] =calif;//se guarda la nota ingresada en la posicion i
    i++;
}
//promedio de calificaciones
float promCalificaciones=0;
float sumaCalific =0;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    sumaCalific = sumaCalific + M[j];
}
promCalificaciones =sumaCalific/n;
System.out.println("Promedio de Notas: "+promCalificaciones);

System.out.println("alumnos con calificación Muy bien: "+muybien);
System.out.println("alumnos con calificación Bien: "+bien);
System.out.println("alumnos calificación Regular: "+regular);
System.out.println("alumnos calificación Mejorar: "+mejorar);
System.out.println("alumnos calificación Insuficiente: "+insuficiente);
System.out.println("******* PROMEDIOS **********");
//calculamos promedio, y el (float) es un casting por que si no redondea para bajo, investiga..
promMuyBien =(float)muybien/n;
promBien =(float)bien/n;
promRegular =(float)regular/n;
promMejorar =(float)mejorar/n;
promInsuficiente =(float)insuficiente/n;
System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos con calificación Muy bien: "+promMuyBien);
System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos con calificación Bien: "+promBien);
System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Regular: "+promRegular);
System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Mejorar: "+promMejorar);
System.out.println("Promedio de alumnos calificación Insuficiente: "+promInsuficiente);

porcentajereprobados=100*aprobados/n;
System.out.println("Porcentaje aprobados: "+porcentajereprobados+" %");

//algoritmo Moda
int maximaVecesQueSeRepite = 0;
int moda = 0;
for(int a=0; a<n; a++){
    int vecesQueSeRepite = 0;
    for(int b=0; b<n; b++){
    if(M[a] == M[b])
    vecesQueSeRepite++;
    }
    if(vecesQueSeRepite > maximaVecesQueSeRepite){
        moda = M[a];
        maximaVecesQueSeRepite = vecesQueSeRepite;
    }  
}
String leyenda =null;
if(maximaVecesQueSeRepite > 1) leyenda =new String("La moda es "+moda+" y se repitió "+maximaVecesQueSeRepite+" veces.");
else leyenda =new String("No existe Moda, ya que no se repite ninguna calificacion");
System.out.println(leyenda);
```