# ¿Programa que guarde calificaciones con for anidado?

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando en linea y me inicie en java tengo que hacer este programa
1. Realiza un programa que calcule porcentaje de aprobados, porcentaje de reprobados y moda de la materia Programación Orientada a Objetos I, con un listado mínimo de 10 estudiantes y al finalizar debe imprimir el listado de los estudiantes indicando el nivel de desempeño de cada uno y las estadísticas generales de la materia.

2. Para ello deberás solicitar se ingrese la calificación de cada alumno y deberás hacer uso de las estructuras de control que se vieron en la Unidad 2 para la solución del planteamiento
3. De acuerdo al valor obtenido en la calificación, mostrarás el desempeño del estudiante en base a lo siguiente
   de 81 a 100 muy bien, de 61 a 80 bien de 41 a 60 regular de 21 a 40 necesitas mejorar de 1 a 20 insuficiente.

llevo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero al momento de anidar otro for para que guarde los que han pasado reprobado y la moda ya no m corre el programa espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Hola, yo respondí a una pregunta muy similar, fíjate acá: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/302409/116640

Comment: gracias juan rom :)