# impresion de numeros ascendentes y descendentes "JAVA"

Tags: java, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Estoy atorado en una parte de un ejercicio donde debo imprimir en pantalla una serie de numeros que previamente ingrese, de manera ascendente y descendente.

La forma ascendente me sale sin problemas, pero el array que deberia mostrar los descendentes no logro que muestre los resultados.

El codigo en cuestion es el siguiente:

```
//impresion en pantalla de resultados
System.out.print("Ascendentes:[");
for(i=0;i<limite;i++){
System.out.print(arreglo[i]+", ");
}
System.out.print("]\n");
//
System.out.print("Descendentes: [");
for(j=0;i>limite;i--){
System.out.print(arreglo[i]+", ");
}
System.out.print("]\n");
```

El resultado sale de la siguiente manera:
Ingresa el limite de numeros a evaluar: 
5
Ascendentes:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ]

Descendentes: []

Algun tip? Estuve buscando pero lo que he encontrado solo me despliega una cadena de datos.

Comment: hola, no te sirvió mi solución?

Comment: si te fijas mi solución es más eficiente por que no tiene que calcular la longitud del arreglo en cada iteración, pero no entiendo que pasa que me botaron en contra..

Comment: y ahora que veo no votaste esta pregunta que te respondí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/302409/116640

Comment: una disculpa Juan, no me habia podido conectar este fin. Ahorita pondre en practica todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i,j;
int arreglo[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int limite =arreglo.length;
System.out.print("Ascendentes:[");
for(i=0; i<limite; i++){
System.out.print(arreglo[i]+", ");
}
System.out.print("]\n");
System.out.print("Descendentes: [");
for(j=limite-1; j>=0;j--){
System.out.print(arreglo[j]+", ");
}
System.out.print("]");
```

Comment: gracias Juan, este arreglo soluciono ese pequeño bache que tenia.

Comment: ahora solo agregue la parte de como sacar el factorial pero me arroja un error al momento de compilar.
Este es todo el codigo:
 `
        //
       
        System.out.print("Factorial: [");
        for (i=0;i<limite;i++){
            if(arreglo[i]%2==0){
                aux=arreglo[i];
                for(int j=aux-1;j>0;j--){
                    aux=aux*j;
             }                   
               
           System.out.print(+arreglo[i]+" "+aux);
           }
         }
    
        System.out.print("]\n");
    
    }
}
`

Comment: Hola! Podrías edita la respuesta con esa nueva implementación  para ver el código mas ordenado?

Answer (score 4):

La solucion a tu problema quedaria de la siguiente manera.

```
        int arreglo[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        System.out.print("Ascendentes:[");
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arreglo[i] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]\n");
        //
        System.out.print("Descendentes: [");
        for (int j = (arreglo.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(arreglo[j] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.print("]\n");
```

Tu problema es que en ascendentes debias de declarar el valor de `j = (arreglo.length - 1)` porque eso te daria en el caso del ejemplo que te proporciona el valor de 6 pero los arreglos siempre comienzan desde 0 y el 6 sobrepasaria el valor del arreglo y en el caso de la condicion tiene que ser `j >= 0` para que de esta forma te imprima hasta el ultimo  numero y de esa forma es como funcionaria tu programa.

Comment: hare pruebas porque veo que se ingresaron los numeros impresos como parte del array, intentare modificando un poco esa parte poniendo que sea igual a los numeros que ingrese previamente al inicio del programa